# How to bind textbox text to the 3rd character of a cell in the database with databindings with code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, data-binding, textbox, ms-access-2010

I have a DataBinding which works.

I would like to give my "Save" Button the function...

that it saves the TextBox.Text to the third character of a cell in the database with databinding code.
(Binding over the properties seems not to work)

Right now I am replacing the whole cell with this (working):

```
bindingSource.DataSource = list[index];
```

And this try is (not working):

```
list[index].CELL_NAME_A.Substring(2, 1) = "A";
```

Ignore the index.

But I wan't to pass the whole letter (TextBox.Text) only to the third character of that cell while ignoring the first two letters.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to bind the third character of the cell in the database to the textbox.

```
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = @"connstr";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constr);
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "select * from Student";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        table = dataSet.Tables[0];
        table.TableName = "Student";
        foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
        {
            item["Name"] = item["Name"].ToString().Substring(2, 1);
        }
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dataSet, "Student.Name"));
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a bindingSource. Can't I work with some bindingSource to get this done?

Comment: @JamesJeffersonJohnson, please provide the related code about your bindSource.